# Login using Facebook and Firebase on a Web Application

Tags: javascript, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I'd like to use Facebook login through Firebase like this:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.

});
```

But I have still some trouble with an "authorization". Here my console error:

[image]

I tried to check "Auth section -> Sign in" in Firebase, here's the picture:

[image]

But that, unfortunately, did not help me. So I checked the Google API console, here's the key:

[image]

The Javascript error appears when I call `signInWithPopup` function.

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: What domain are you serving the app from?

Comment: I think you may have some problem with your browser ApiKey. There may be referrer restrictions on it. I noticed that because you got a 403 in your request. Can you show us the response of that getProjectConfig request?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've already registered your application with Facebook, you need to add your Facebook application id and secret in Firebase and then register the OAuth redirect with Facebook.

[Sign-in Providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAboI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Of course @bojeil, this is the response of "getProjectConfig" request.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The referrer https://mywebsite-28961.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=AIzaSXXXXXXXXXXXJxJtYyQc&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=3.2.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.fr.rHHEwUgDOpI.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCM__323woIJL0YGmPpXSAOboj0rkQ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=952309991745"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The referrer https://mywebsite-28961.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=AIzaSXXXXXXXXXXXJxJtYyQc&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=3.2.1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.fr.rHHEwUgDOpI.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCM__323woIJL0YGmPpXSAOboj0rkQ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
 }
}
```